# Splitting an email column into three columns in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've an email column values in employee table:

```
Email
regan.manning@cresa.com
miang.luso@praxis.com
selin.robert@cummins.com
```

I want to split the email into three columns like:

```
FirstName        LastName              DomainName
--------------------------------------------------
regan            manning               @cresa.com
miang            luso                  @praxis.com
selin            robert                @cummins.com
```

Comment: Ugly problem.  What about an edge case like `jon.m.skeet@google.co.uk` ?

Comment: What SQL Server version?

Comment: and what if the email starts with lastname in stead of firstname ?

Comment: If it is your employee table, does it not have firstname and lastname columns apart from the email column ?

Comment: no its only have Email column and I've to split the one column into three columns and ll have to compare with other tables with respective FirstName & LastName as derived...

Comment: am using Sql Server 2014

Answer (score 2):

One method uses `apply`:

```
select t.*, v.domain, v2.firstname, v2.lastname
from t cross apply
     (values(stuff(email, 1, charindex('@', email), '') as domain,
             left(email, charindex('@', email)
            )
     ) v(domain, name) cross apply
     (values (left(name, charindex('.')),
              stuff(name, 1, charindex('.', name), '')
             )
     ) v2(lastname, firstname;
```

Comment: I want it using substring & charindex... would u plz update me the query...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 

substring( @email , 0 , CHARINDEX('.' , @email) ) ,

substring( @email , CHARINDEX('.',@email)+1 , CHARINDEX('@' , @email) - CHARINDEX('.' , @email)-1 ),

substring( @email , CHARINDEX('@' , @email) , LEN(@email) - CHARINDEX('@' , @email)+1 )

from employee;
```

--replace @email with name of your email column

**Easier version to understand:**

```
DECLARE @email NVARCHAR(30) = 'selin.robert@cummins.com';
DECLARE @dot INT =CHARINDEX( '.' , @email );
DECLARE @atrate INT =CHARINDEX( '@' , @email );
DECLARE @len INT =LEN( @email );

SELECT 
substring( @email , 0 , @dot ),
substring( @email , @dot+1 , @atrate - @dot-1 ),
substring( @email, @atrate , @len - @atrate+1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Substring` & `Charindex` Function to check the `.`, `@` & retrieve the data :

```
SELECT @email [Email],
       SUBSTRING(@email, 1, CHARINDEX('.', @email)-1) [FirstName],
       SUBSTRING(@email, CHARINDEX('.', @email)+1, CHARINDEX('@', @email)-CHARINDEX('.', @email)-1) [LastName],
       SUBSTRING(@email, CHARINDEX('@', @email), LEN(@email)) [DomainName] from <table_name>;
```

Result :

```
Email                   FirstName    LastName   DomainName
miang.luso@praxis.com   miang        luso       @praxis.com
```